# Proving that there do not exist integer $m$ and $n$ such that $12m+15n=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Propostion:
**There do not exist integer $m$ and $n$ such that $12m+15n=1$**

It seem obvious but I am not sure how to show this.

Proposition 2:
**If there exist integer m and n such that $12M+15n=1$ then $m$ and $n$ are both positive**.

Well clearly the antecent if false on this one. So nothing can really be proved.

But I am not sure how to show this.

Comment: Proposition 2 is dealt with per ex falso quodlibet. For proposition 1, why does it seem obvious?

Comment: $12m+15n = 3(4m+5n) \neq 1$, since there is no integer $z \in \Bbb Z$ such that $3z = 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$12m+15n=3(4m+5n)$ is always a multiple of $3$, but $1$ is not.

Answer (score 5):

No. By the Bezout's lemma $12m+15n=1\iff \gcd(12,15)=1$ which's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The left hand side is divisble by three, the right hand side is not.